# what status code to throw when there is a concurrency error?

Tags: rest, api, http, http-status-codes

I have a rest that receives among other things, a date and with it, makes a reservation. The problem occurs when 2 people "at the same time" try to book on the same day, at the same time.

Obviously, the first one who makes the request, will be able to book the appointment, so I will return a status of 200. On the other hand, the one that arrives later, will make the same request, but the server will throw an error because it can not reserve the Same appointment (already reserved). In this case, what http state code should be thrown?

A family code of 500 would not seem right, because the exception that is thrown, is caused by the very logic of the business.

On the other hand, a state code of the family of 400 would not seem right either because the request is well formulated

Thanks!

Comment: 409 - Conflict?

Comment: A 409 error is probably what you're looking for. For you reference - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @MAT if you're going to refer to a list of error codes, why not use the actual canonical list? https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml

Comment: Nice one @EricStein, will refer to the canonical list you suggested going forward.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was researching this myself and jonrsharpe's suggestion of 409 Conflict is most appropriate.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8:

The 409 (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be
able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server
SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
to recognize the source of the conflict.

Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request.  For
example, if versioning were being used and the representation being
PUT included changes to a resource that conflict with those made by
an earlier (third-party) request, the origin server might use a 409
response to indicate that it can't complete the request.  In this
case, the response representation would likely contain information
useful for merging the differences based on the revision history.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate error code depends on the implementation and where the concurrency error is detected.

If you use Http If-Match header the Http specification requires a 412  precondition failed (error because of header information), while 409 is used if the entity would cause a conflict.

In a race condition two requests could pass the If-Match check and only the database or the domain layer detects the conflict. In that case I would return a 409, because the precondition was valid.

If you wouldn't use If-Match and ETags, but use a version id in the body then you need to use 409. Be aware that `DELETE` should not have a body.

[The "Zalando RESTful API and Event Guidelines" has a great comparison of various options for optimistic locking](https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/#optimistic-locking)